# Application icon not refreshing

Tags: windows-mobile, icons

I made a win ce application setup project. I installed it in Datalogic memor. After it, I just saw the small white window icon [image] at my application on Desktop. I also tried it in Motorola. I could see my actual icon. Why not get in Datalogic? Please share me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not certain I fully understand the question, but WinMo caches the Start Menu icons.  Soft reset the device and it will reload it.  If tht's not the issue, you need to elaborate/clarify the question.

Comment: It's caused of setup project's crush. Firstly I tried to do clean solution. Secondly, I did soft reset the device. Finally, I created a new setup project. Now it works. Thank you, @ctacke